# Conditionally displaying nested relationships

Tags: relationships, nesting

I have a bit of a complex relationship situation I'm trying to figure out in EE.

My channels consist of **case-studies**, **clients**, and **services**.

- I have a relationship field within each case-studies entry where I
  relate a **client** and **service**.
- Within the **clients** channel I relate items from the **service** channel.

I want to create tab-based clients page that lists **clients** segmented by the 4 **services**, with a link under each client to a page that lists their related **case-studies**.

Now I can list the clients fine, and the tabs are working the way they should, the problem I'm having is checking whether a client has related case studies or not and only displaying a link to that page **IF that client has some related case-studies**.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="services" entry_id="4"}
<!-- I'm in the services channel, now I want to loop through the clients that are related to this service -->
  {parents field="client_related_service"}
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 client-details">
    <p> <img src="{parents:client_logo}" class="img-responsive" alt="{title}"/></p>
    <p> {parents:client_description} </p>
    <!-- ONLY ADD THIS IF CLIENT HAS CASE-STUDIES RELATED TO IT, CAN'T FIGURE OUT HOW TO DO THIS-->
    <p> <a href="{site_url}index.php/clients/{parents:url_title}">See how we helped {parents:title}</a> </p>
    </div>
  {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: You don't mention how your Case Studies are related to each client - via the Client entry, or via the Case Studies entry?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear but that's what I mean in the first bullet point. When I create a new case study I have a field where I choose the related client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship tags are nest-able by continuing with the colon syntax:

```
{parents:parents field="case_study_related_client"}
<p><a href="{parents:parents:title_permalink="case-studies/index"}">See how we helped {parents:title}</a></p>
{/parents:parents}
```